# angular 5 send request header and receive response header using HttpClient

Tags: angular5, httpclient

I have written an authentication service in Angular 5 which does a GET request to my backend using the HttpClient class.

My request looks like this:

```js
headers =  new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                             .set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', 'sdfhjsdgh');

          const options = ({ headers: headers});
          this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/display', options)
         .filter(data => data.status === 200 || data.status === 206)
         .map((res) => this.success(res))
         .catch((res) => this.failure(res, service));
```

How do I access the authorization header of the response?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Which programming language you get header information?

Comment: @SwapnilYeole **angular** is not a programming language. It is a framework.

Comment: agree @AnuradhaGunasekara